# How do I get multiple levels of lists of items using Reactive Extensions in C#

Tags: c#, .net, mvvm, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have a list of items which I am returning using Reactive, in C# and SQL Server. I can create this first list fine, using a stream and then doing a `.ToProperty` on a `ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObserable`.

Now, once I have this list of items, I want to then go and query a different API on the same server, to get a list of sub items for each of these parents.

Eg:

- Car 1

  - Tyre 1
  - Tyre 2
  - Tyre 3
  - Tyre 4
- Car 2

  - Tyre 1
  - Tyre 2
  - Tyre 3
  - Tyre 4

I am new to reactive, and I understand so far about the `ReactiveObject`, the `ObjectAsPropertyHelper`, and how you make your public property on the ViewModel get the `.Value` from the `PropertyHelper`. I just can't understand how to get that second list of items after the main list is populated.

So to load my cars, I do:

```
LoadCars = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => GetCars());

_carsWithTyreViewModels = LoadCars
            .Select(x => x.OrderBy(m => m.Car.Name)
            .ToList())
            .ToProperty(this, x => x.CarsWithTyresViewModels);

LoadCars.Execute();
```

-

```
private IObservable<IEnumerable<CarWithTyresViewModel>> GetCars()
{
        return
            _carService.GetAllCarsStream().
                Select(x => x.Select(CreateCarAndLoadTyres));
}

private CarWithTyresViewModel CreateCarAndLoadTyres(Car car)
{
        var carWithTyresViewModel = new CarWithTyresViewModel(car);

        LoadTyresForCar = ReactiveCommand.CreateAsyncObservable(_ => GetTyresForCar(car));

        ???? WHAT DO I PUT HERE ????
        /*
        My thoughts were to define a LINQ to select the TyreViewModels and then to assign those to carWithTyresViewModel.Tyres, and then LoadTyresForCar.Execute(car), which would then send it to the API.

        Another thought was I should make the TyreViewModels also use the ObservableAsPropertyHelper and do a ToProperty lower down the list in another viewmodel.

        /*

        return carWithTyresViewModel;
}
```

My API works if I hit the URL in a web browser, I get back 3 tyres that I have defined for a car. (`/api/tyres/car543`) and my cars come from `/api/cars` which also works.

My end goal is I am showing all this in a TreeView of components.

Any advice? Need more info? :)